# Error with sem function at R : differences in factors

Tags: r, structural-equation-model

I wanted to use the function sem (with the package lavaan) on my data in R :

```
Model1<- 'Transfer~Amotivation+Gender+Age
Amotivation~Gender+Age

transfer are 4 questions with a 5 point likert scale 
Amotivation: 4 questions with a 5 pint likert scale
Gender: 0 (=male) and 1 (=female)
Age: just the different ages
```

And i got next error:

```
in getDataFull (data= data, group =  group, grow.label = group.label,:
lavaan WARNING: some observed variances are (at least) a factor 100 times larger than others; please rescale
```

Is anybody familiar with this error? Does it influence my results? Do I have to change anything? I really don't know what this error means.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the method, but from the error message something like a log-transformation might be appropriate.

Comment: Hi.  Please read the info on how to post a useful question.  We need to know the code you're using -- what package, what function, and a reproducible small sample of your data.

Comment: I'm sorry, I hope this is more useful. I'm using R on another computer without internet connection, so i can't copy/paste anything.

Comment: In `R`, a "warning" is issued when something might not be completely kosher but it's not an error.  My guess here is that the author wants you to be aware of the range of variances, and that it could lead to rounding or scaling inaccuracies in the final output.

Answer (score 0):

Your scales are not equivalent. Your gender variables are constrained to be either 0 or 1. Amotivation is constrained to be between 1 and 5, but age is even less constrained. I created some sample data for gender, age, and amotivation. You can see that the variance for the age variable is over 4,000 times higher than the variance for gender, and about 500 times higher than sample amotivation data.

```
gender  <- c(0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1)
age <- c(18,42,87,12,24,26,98,84,23,12,95,44,54,23,10,16)
set.seed(42)
amotivation <- rnorm(16, 3, 1.5)
var(gender)      #    0.25 variance
var(age)         # 1017.27 variance
var(amotivation) #    2.21 variance
```

I'm not sure how the unequal variances influence your results, or if you need to do anything at all. To make your age variable more closely match the amotivation scale, you could transform the data so that it's also on a 5 point scale.

```
newage <- age/max(age)*5
var(newage) # 2.65 variance
```

You could try running the analysis both ways (using your original data and the transformed data) and see if there are differences.